Does pre-fortis clipping have any effect on unstressed syllables?
In books such as J.C. Wells' Longman Pronunciation Dictionary (LPD) or Collins and et al.'s Practical English Phonetics and Phonology, there's no mentioning that clipping only affects stressed syllables. The only condition is that the fortis is at the coda of the syllable containing the clipped vowel. To quote one source from Well's blog:

English vowels are subject to pre-fortis clipping, then, when they are followed by a fortis consonant within the same syllable.

However, Wikipedia puts it straightforward that pre-fortis clipping only affects stressed ones. Thought there's no reference for the claim on Wikipedia page, I find from many recordings on various dictionaries that this claim seems reasonable.
Furthermore, in the section on Devoice, in Well's LDP, the prof. wrote:

A devoiced lenis does not sound quite like a fortis. Quite apart from differences such as those described in the notes at ASPIRATION and CLIPPING, /b/, /d/, /g/ etc. have less articulatory force than /p/, /t/, /k/ etc. This may be due to the vocal folds, which in the case of a devoiced lenis sound probably remain in the narrowed "whisper" configuration, distinct from their wide open configuration for a true voiceless (fortis) sound.

Which seems to assert the clipping effect does exist on unstressed syllables also.
Are there some researches on this?

Not aware of any research, but in my own speech, pre-fortis clipping definitely applies in unstressed syllables as well. There’s a clear clipping distinction between edit (with clipping) and bedded (without clipping).
